# Split string containing "." without using inbuilt functions

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

I need to split the string and create a list of words without using inbuilt functions. Please help I'm missing something in the logic

```
st="i.like.this.very.much"
wordlist=[]
i=0
j=0
while i<len(st)-4:
    if st[i]==".":
        i+=1
    else:
        j=i
        word=""
        while st[j]!=".":
            word+=st[j]
            j+=1
            print(word)
        wordlist.append(word)
        i+=len(word)       
print(wordlist)
```

Output:
C:\Users\Desktop>python raja1.py

```
i.like.this.very.much
i
l
li
lik
like
t
th
thi
this
v
ve
ver
very
['i', 'like', 'this', 'very']
```

Comment: Why is your outer loop condition subtracting 4 (which happens to be the length of `much` and the number of "." in the string) from `len(st)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick-and-dirty solution that doesn't use `len()` or `append()` (and you can remove `print()` later):

```py
st="i.like.this.very.much"
sp=[]
c=""
for s in st:
    if s == ".": 
        sp=sp+[c]
        c=""
    else: c+=s
if s != ".": sp=sp+[c]
print(sp)
```

The output is `['i', 'like', 'this', 'very', 'much']`.

Comment: Why dirty? Simple and pretty explicit.

Comment: I only meant that I haven't tested it very thoroughly and I haven't thought very hard about what should happen to strings like "..string.with...weird.periods..". I think in this case it will add a bunch of empty strings. I'm not sure what the desired behavior is. Edit: Also, the variable names are not very descriptive.

Comment: It's amazing how well you worked with list and strings there. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Your only problem is that you've neglected to pick up the final word, because you stop 4 characters early for no apparent reason.  Your loop only dumps the word if it ends with a period.

Run through the end of the string.  Then simply add one more `append` *after* the loop -- but check that you do have a word to add, in case the input ended with a period:

```
if word:
    wordlist.append(word)
```

Also, you say that you can't use any built-ins, but your supposed solution uses `len`.

Comment: I stopped at 4 as it was giving me an indexError. Sorry, I have just started competitive coding so please forgive me for my foolishness. But the approach you said is giving the same indexError. I removed the (-4) and traversed through whole list. I can't figure out why is that happening. Please help

Comment: I can't "help" with a problem you didn't fully specify, and for which you post no code.
Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Also think about whether this is a continuation of the current problem (likely), or a separate problem.